# Are there CLI programs or commands to manipulate *.gdbm files

Tags: linux, database

`Modem-manager-gui` stores it's all the messages to a `*.gdbm` file. Deleting `sms.gdbm` file removes all the messages but I'm trying to do a shell program to delete received and sent separately. I tried `man gdbm`. I don't think I could understand the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy way is probably writing an improvised tool in a bit more powerful scripting language.

I've just written one in Ruby's [GDBM](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/gdbm/rdoc/GDBM.html) (no error handling):

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'gdbm'

dbfile, op, key, val, = ARGV

GDBM.open(dbfile) do |db|
  case op
  when "set"
    db[key] = val
  when "get"
    puts db[key]
  when "rm"
    db.delete(key)
  else
    db.each do |k, v|
      puts "#{k.inspect} = #{v.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

Save this script as `gdbmtool`.  You can manipulate any key-values in the gdbm like this:

```
$ chmod +x gdbmtool
$ ./gdbmtool database.gdbm set abc def
$ ./gdbmtool database.gdbm set 123 456
$ ./gdbmtool database.gdbm get abc
def
$ ./gdbmtool database.gdbm
"abc" = "def"
"123" = "456"
$ ./gdbmtool database.gdbm rm abc
$ ./gdbmtool database.gdbm
"123" = "456"
```

Comment: any way i can display tables or fields that gdbm contains and delete all records that specific table or field got? Thank you so much for the code!

Comment: @DScript You'd better ask another question for that.  Because most of us don't know about the structure of `sms.gdbm` at all, you should provide the content shown by `gdbmtool sms.gdbm` as well as brief spec description you want to achieve.

Comment: ok sir, one minute!